# Flutter apk builds, installs but then will not open

Tags: android, flutter

I'm attempting to create apk for my flutter app. It works when running flutter run on both emulator and device.

When running:
flutter build apk

Get success and apk. When copying apk to device it installs but then cannot be opened. (After install button to open is grayed out and finding app in app draw opens up the app info page). Have tired apk on multiple devices.

flutter run --release works

I've followed the steps to migrate to Androidx and have checked all packages build.gradle to ensure all are compileSdkVersion 28.

I've tried running on stable, master and beta flutter branch.

Running:
flutter build apk --release gives (on flutter beta branch)

```
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            2.8s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (21.2MB).
```

EDIT: 
The plot thickens xD. I can launch the app from deeplinks, but using the app icon always launches into settings.

Comment: Having some issue here, any solution??

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to

> android\app\build.gradle
>   Inside android {
>   }

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I gave that a go but am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the package app availability installed which was using the compileSdkVersion of 27. Changing this to 28 in that package's build.gradle seemed to fix it.

The easiest solution was just to swap that package out.